# flash[:notice] & flash[:error] + refresh button = disappearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My view with flashes

```
<% unless flash[:notice].blank? %>
<div id="notification_notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>

<% unless flash[:error].blank? %>
<div id="notification_error"><%= flash[:error] %></div>
<% end %>
```

Question: If error or success it shows very nice. But when I;m do refresh my error or notices are dispersing. Why? How to edit this bug? Or everything is nice in rails?

Comment: why do you need them again, and when they should be deleted. You want them to be stored forever or how?

Comment: so when should be deleted this notification?

Comment: never! it always will be there! oo, i have question, how i can do this: i have error, nice, i do refresh and its redirecting me to another controller (or for example to google.com)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of rails, the flash messages will be cleared after one request.

Comment: and there no way to return them back? :{

Comment: I am not sure about this, but if want to keep something in hand to make it available across requests then use session. But you need to clear it when you don't want to use them anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The flash will be emptied after the next request. To keep it, you can do this in your controller:

```
flash.keep(:notice)
```

See [the Documentation on **FlashHash**](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Flash/FlashHash.html)